# Javascript problem with form enctype, uploadify script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

I have a problem while I need to send data using uploadify script.

For first time, uploadify script is installed correctly, everything works fine. But I need to use uploaded data (via uploadify script) for mysql and others.

Here is my code for calling uploadify script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader' : '/uplod/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script' : '/uplod/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uplod/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder' : '/uplod/uploads/',
    'auto' : true,
    'multi' : false,
    'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data){
        var form = document.forms['form'];
        var i = 0;
        var el = document.createElement("input");
            el.type = "hidden";
            el.name = "test";
            el.id = "test2";
            el.value = fileObj.name;
            form.appendChild(el); },
            'onAllComplete': function(event,data) { document.getElementById('form').submit();},
 });
});
</script>
```

I found this code at: http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/7102/for-all-those-who-struggle-on-inserting-filenames-into-a-db-after-uploading/p1

It`s about how to callback after file is uploaded.

Here is uploadify.php code:

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_FILES)) {
   $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
   $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
   $targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
   move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
   echo '0'; // Required to trigger onComplete function on Mac OSX (same for linux and        windows as it seems)

   }
   else { // Required to trigger onComplete function on Mac OSX (same for linux and windows as it seems)
   echo '1';
   $video = $_POST[test];
   $textfield = $_POST[textfield];
   echo $video;
   echo $textfield;
   }
  ?>
```

And here is form which I need to create how I be able to getting this work.

```
  <form id="form" name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadify/uploadify.php">
  <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
  </form>
```

Problem is here, when I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` uploadify.php writes to me 0, when I delete `enctype="multipart/form-data"` writes to me 1. And that`s what I need. As you can see from code, I put some stupid code at end of uploadify.php to test it.

I think this don't work because in javascript code, I don't write anywhere enctype. maybe I wrong. 
I tried editing this:

```
            var form = document.forms['form'].enctype  = "multipart/form-data";
```

but nothing,

also I tried:

`'onAllComplete': function(event,data) { document.getElementById('form').enctype;
                                                document.getElementById('form').submit();},`

but again nothing. All help is welcome...

P.S This is test example, for this code I don't need multipart/form-data but on project which testing, I need multipart/form-data because I`m testing uploadify script for small video uploader, and I need a cover picture for each video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var form = document.forms['form'];
    form.enctype  = "multipart/form-data";
```

instead of

```
var form = document.forms['form'].enctype  = "multipart/form-data";
```

But as you don't use multi-uploads, I dont see any need to do this in 2 steps(first send the file, then the complete form).
See the [scriptData](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/scriptdata/)-option, it allows you to send both, the file and additional data:

```
'scriptData'  : {'textfield':$('#textfield').val()}
```